# Is there a way to initialize a UICollectionView with a content offset?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I was wondering if there was any way to initialize a custom `UICollectionView` with a content offset so that when it first appears the collection view is offset? I tried setting the content offset in the convenienceinit of my custom `UICollectionView` but this did not affect the content offset when the collection view first appeared. Thanks

The convenience initializer of my custom class:

```
convenience init() {
  layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
  self.init(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
  self.backgroundColor = UIHelper.primaryBG
  self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

  contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                              left: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2,
                              bottom: 0,
                              right: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)

  // Doesn't work
  setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.5, y: 0), animated: false) 

  self.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
  self.delegate = self
  self.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: are you trying to have the collectionview slide in or something? What's the goal here

Comment: @Jay I would like the collection view to be scrolled to the end when the collection view appears

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, when the collectionview loads, you want it to show the last cell on screen?

Comment: Yes, like if you were to load in a list of followers and when the list loads it is scrolled to the bottom. I am looking for the collection view to be scrolled to the end when the collection view appears

Comment: Why don't you first set the collectionview alpha to 0, then use the delegate method collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexNumber, section: sectionNumber), at: .right, animated: false) , then fade in collectionview alpha back to 1, so it'll be at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `setContentOffset` out of the init and calling it after data is actually in the collectionView such as after a call to `reloadData`

Comment: I think this might be the only way... OP wants it inside the `init`, but at that time you still don't have any data

Comment: Nice, thanks @Ryanavocado. I solved it now by calling setContentOffset in numberOfItemsInSection